# Strech ToggleButton with icon inside

Tags: android, image, user-interface, icons, togglebutton

I have follow situation.
I am using toggle button with custom background and image. For image composition I have created layer with puts my @drawable/image over @drawable/background, in addition to this my @drawable/background is a selector of two backgrounds: check and unchecked.

Now I have 5 button and all this buttons are placed into LinearLayout horizontally, I have tried to fill spaces by adding layout-weight="1", but in this case icons are stretchered too. 
I have tried scale, but scale should be root element, not part of my selector or layer.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/ui_bottom_shadow"
      android:elevation="2dp"
      android:paddingTop="5dp"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp">

      <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/button_back"
           style="@style/IconButton"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_call"
                    style="@style/IconButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_favourite"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/button_favourite"
                style="@style/IconButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn=""
                android:background="@drawable/ui_favourite_button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post screenshots? It is nearly impossible for us to figure out what is going on with your situation.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Please take a look, question updated